# Scrolling in DropDownlist customize

Tags: javascript, scroll

im using this `DropDownList` for searching item and i have a problem my problem is how can i scrolling in this `DropDownList` with up and down in Keyboard?
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/8/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since my first solution wasn't working properly when more items were added i adjusted it a little. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/12/)

What i did:

First of all, i checked the position of the `storeTarget` and `#search_results` and logged it into the console to figure out what was causing the problem.
(This is something you could've done by yourself btw...)
What i found out then was, that, after a couple of items, the top position of the `storeTarget`item was higher than the visible area of the `#search_results`.

so i changed the parameter of

```
 $("#search_results").scrollTop(storeTarget.offset().top);
```

to scroll a little further than the current position and to make it smoother changed the check in the if-clause:

```
if(storeTarget.offset().top>220){
       $("#search_results").scrollTop($("#search_results").scrollTop()+40);
       console.log(storeTarget.offset().top);
       console.log($("#search_results").scrollTop());
       }
```

I didn't check for the case when the user goes up, that's left up to you to figure out.

[here's a working fiddle based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/9/)

END EDIT

What i did:

when moving up or down with the keys i check if the `offset().top` value of the `storeTarget` is greater or lesser than 200 (you may change that depending on the size of your list) and if so, we scroll the top of `#search-results` to the
top of your `storeTarget` :

```
if(storeTarget.offset().top>200){
   $("#search_results").scrollTop(storeTarget.offset().top);
}
```

Comment: hi, when the number of lists increases, this code is not suitable.

Comment: sorry, but could you clarify that? when the number of dropdown-lists increases? or when the number of items increases? and why is it not suitable / what problems do you face?

Comment: There is a problem when the number of cases increases. pleas look at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/7h0pavzb/11/